# Exception in thread "main" dropbox application with java

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, dropbox

I'm trying to make a simple application with Java, using Eclipse that could upload a file from my computer to Dropbox but whenever I compile, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet
    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.streamRequest(RESTUtility.java:164)
    at com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession.setUpToken(WebAuthSession.java:218)
    at com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession.getAuthInfo(WebAuthSession.java:158)
    at com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession.getAuthInfo(WebAuthSession.java:128)
    at DropboxAuthTest.main(DropboxAuthTest.java:47)
```

Can you help me figure this out? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a library. Looks like [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

Comment: The library is there, I've added it earlier, and when I click RESTUtility.java, it appears to me "Source not found" and if I try adding the source manually, and compile again the project, nothing is changed.